# Which registers are protected from user space in linux?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, kernel, cpu-registers

How can I find out which registers are protected by the Linux kernel to keep user assembly from writing to them?

Comment: Well, control and debug registers are typically only accessible in ring0, if that is what you mean...

Comment: [Can an x86 CPU read the value of any register while in user mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55464162) points out that x86 *can* allow user-space to read CR0 via `smsw` (store machine status word), but Linux configures it not to (so `smsw` is privileged).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, note that the Linux kernel itself doesn't really protect registers. All it does is make sure user applications run with privilege level 3 (lowest privilege). From that point, it's the processor that enforces protection of registers.

Here is a list of registers that are only accessible from privilege level 0 (i.e., from the kernel):

- Control registers (`CR0` - `CR4`)
- `GDTR`, `LDTR` and `IDTR` (Global/Local/Interrupt Descriptor Table Register)
- `TR` (Task Register)
- Debug registers (`DR0` - `DR7`)
- All Model Specific Registers (`MSR`s)

You should read Chapter 5 of [Intel's System Programming Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) for a detailed explanation on protection on the x86.

Comment: The x86 segment registers (ss, cs, ds, es, fs, gs) are also not exactly fair game for user space. (largely read-only as far as I know; fs is used to identify a thread and index into its thread-local storage, for example)

Comment: @pmjordan: Thanks. I didn't add them at first because I do not seem to find any official documentation about that. I tested that reading them is allowed and direct writing (through a `mov`) is not. However, I'm not sure whether indirectly writing them (through a far `call`, for example) is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that manual and felt overwhelmed. I needed to be shown the right direction. So I'm wondering, for older architectures that do not offer this kind of protection, changing these registers wouldn't be a problem I take it. It seems to me that os security is only as good as the cpu architecture security features.

Comment: All OS security is based around CPU protection features. But you'd have to go back many, many years to find a processor that didn't support some form of protection. Also, you *can* write to the segment registers from usermode - but the values have to make sense when married up to the GDT (which, as you say, is restricted). Basically, you can only set the segment registers to those valid values allowed by the OS which makes trying to alter them largely pointless. But other registers (like the control registers) can *never* be written from ring 3, even if their values are valid.

Comment: @adelphus: Thanks for the clarification on the segment registers. I took a closer look at the manual and AFAICS, the same restrictions for moving values to the segment registers hold in all rings so I removed them from my answer.